# Doesn't work + on/in/with

Tags: prepositions

I've seen `doesn't work` + `on/in/with`. Which one is correct?

> 1. This solution doesn't work __ me.
> 2. This USB doesn't work __ my PC.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me.
This USB doesn't work with my PC.

Comment: Are you speaking about the USB in both sentences? Is that the context in both? Or are they intended to present different scenarios?

Comment: Do you have poison ivy?  Are you trying to turn back into human form after competing in an underwater competition where you needed gills? Are you trying to strip paint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that it isn't the meaning of "work" you need help with, it is the words *on*, *in* and *with*.

*Work **on*** means that whatever follows is the medium on which something is working.

*Work **in***, as you would expect, means something is working *inside*, or *within* what follows.

*Work **with*** means that the two things are working *together*, or in connection with one another.

An additional preposition you didn't mention is **for**, which would be used to show that something is working *for* or *on behalf of* the subject.

In your examples I would use:

> This solution doesn't work **for** me.

I am assuming that you are speaking about something tech-related as in your next example, and the solution in question might not work **on** your computer, but it isn't working **for** you, because you're not a computer, the solution was not being *applied to you*.

> This USB doesn't work **on** my PC.

This would be **on** because the USB port is *a part of your computer*. I am assuming that you are talking about the USB port.

If on the other hand you were using the term "USB" as many do to describe a USB drive or some other USB connected device then you are speaking about two things working together, so you could say:

> This USB [device] doesn't work **with** my PC.

Comment: To "work on" usually implies some sort of applied effort. Thus, if the OP were talking about a USB port I would say, "This USB on my PC doesn't work." Otherwise, I agree with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

**work** has many possible meanings, and the three prepositions that you suggested have even more meanings. Here are some of the meanings that could possibly apply:

[on](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on):

> 5 Having (the thing mentioned) as a target, aim, or focus
>
> 6 (often followed by a noun without a determiner) having (the thing mentioned) as a medium for transmitting or storing information.
>
> This solution doesn't work **on** me - meaning 5
>   This USB doesn't work **on** my PC. - meaning 6

[in](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in)

None of the meanings apply, unless you intend swallowing the solution or placing the USB completely inside the computer.

[with](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/with):

> 1 Accompanied by (another person or thing
>
> 3 Indicating the instrument used to perform an action.
>
> 7 In relation to.
>
> This solution doesn't work **with** me - meaning 3 or 7
>   This USB doesn't work **with** my PC. - meanings 1 or 3

Comment: So I can use both `with` and `on ` in two sentences in my post, which one sounds more natural?

Comment: Also `for` was mentioned in the comment.

Comment: It's not a question of which sounds more natural... it is about what meaning you want to convey, and that depends largely on the context. In the first sentence, if the solution is some medical treatment, then **on** is probably best. If you are expressing an opinion about whether a particular solution to a problem sounds right , **for** would be the best choice. If you are talking about whether the solution involves your participation, **with** is the best choice.